# htaccess Subdomain RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've been trying to rewrite the following URL:

> http://subdomain.domain.com/pages/my100page.html

to:

> http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?id=my100page

This is what I came up with after researching:

> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*).html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]

But that didn't work, I ended up on a 404 error page. My .htaccess file is stored in the root of my website (not the subdomain folder), if that is any help.

How could I get this to work?

Thanks,
Daviga404

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have directories like that

```
MainSite/
  ---SubDomain/
  ---.htaccess
```

If the DocumentRoot of your subdomain is the SubDomain directory, you should put your .htaccess file in the SubDomain directory and simply use the RewriteRule Directive :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*).html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this help

Mimiz